# API token authentication with an additional condition

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

I am using laravel5.5 api_token to authenticate api requests (auth:api middelware).
how to add an additional condition and make laravel check the user's is_active column. If the api_token is valid and the user is_active continue if not return  a json error.

Answer (score 0):

Add a new [middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/middleware) for is_active check.